# Need help finding why code is giving me a HTTP 401 error for twitter bot

Tags: python, json, api, twitter, bots

having trouble seeing as to why my code is giving me a Stream encountered HTTP error: 401 for my twitter bot. If anyone could help me out, that would be great. I've already tried changing the clock on my computer to match the clock twitter uses but it just won't work (either because I'm doing it wrong or because of something else). I really have no idea what to do, any help would be appreciated.

```
import tweepy
import keys
from textblob import TextBlob


class TweetListener(tweepy.Stream):
    """Handled incoming tweet stream"""

    def __int__(self, limit):
        """Create instance variables for tracking number of tweets"""
        self.tweet_count = 0
        self.TWEET_LIMIT = limit
        super().__init__(api)  # call superclasses init

    def on_conect(self):
        """Called when your connection attempt is successful, enabling
        you to perform appropriate application tasks at that point"""
        print("Connection successful\n")

    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            tweet_text = status.extended_tweet.full_text
        except:
            tweet_text = status.text
        print(f'Screen name: {status.user.screen_name}')
        print(f'Language: {status.lang}')
        print(f'Status: {tweet_text}')

        if status.lang != 'en':
            print(f'Translated: {TextBlob(tweet_text).translate()}')
        print()
        self.tweet_count += 1

        # if TWEET_LIMIT is reached, return false to termine streaming
        return self.tweet_count != self.TWEET_LIMIT


stream = TweetListener('consumer_key',
                       'consumer_secret',
                       'access_token',
                       'access_token_secret')
stream.filter(track=['python'])


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys.consumer_key, keys.consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(keys.access_token, keys.access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

tweet_listener = TweetListener(api)
tweet_stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=tweet_listener)
tweet_stream.filter(track=['Mars Rover'], is_async=True)
```

Comment: What's your tweepy version?

Comment: I'm using 4.10.0

Answer (score 0):

If you created your Twitter app after April 29 2022 you will no longer have access to the v1.1 filtered stream API and will need to use v2. This is documented on the Twitter developer forums.

New Twitter Developer Apps:

> will not be able to gain access to v1.1 statuses/sample and v1.1
> statuses/filter

https://twittercommunity.com/t/deprecation-announcement-removing-compliance-messages-from-statuses-filter-and-retiring-statuses-sample-from-the-twitter-api-v1-1/170500

Tweepy v4 can access Twitter API v2 but you will need to use a different set of coding methods.